# Configuring gmusicbrowser to copy now playing to X clipboard

Tags: command-line, xorg, clipboard

I'm trying to get gmusicbrowser to copy song information to my X.org clipboard with the Now Playing plugin. For on song change, in the plugin's configuration, I have

```
echo "%a - %t (from %l, %y)" | xclip -i -selection "clip-board"
```

which shows echo as the command and every chunk as an argument (e.g. "..." is arg1, | is arg2, etc.)

```
ian@iris:~$ echo -e "test" | xclip -i -selection "clip-board"
ian@iris:~$ xclip -o -selection "clip-board"
test
```

I'm then able to see 'test' as resulting from a paste into another window. However, when a song changes, this isn't the result!

I'm running xubuntu 12.04.2 with gmusicbrowser 1.1.9-1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to create a bash script

```
echo "${@}" | xclip -i -selection "clip-board"
```

and call it from the Now playing plugin

```
bash /home/ian/scripts/gmb-np.sh "%a - %t (from %l, %y)"
```